# ValueError: `validation_data` should be a tuple

Tags: python, keras, image-segmentation, data-generation

I'm am working on some code and was wondering how I can resolve the error below? I am using class generator(keras.utils.Sequence) for more data generator. I am working with dicom images and trying to implement a keras resnet50_unet model. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
history = model.fit_generator(train_gen, validation_data=valid_gen, 
                          epochs=25, steps_per_epoch = 200,shuffle=True, 
verbose=2)



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-8e6b34e90593> in <module>()
  1 history = model.fit_generator(train_gen, validation_data=valid_gen, 
----> 2                               epochs=25, steps_per_epoch = 
200,shuffle=True, verbose=2)
  3 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in 
wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
 89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name +
 90                               '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, 
 stacklevel=2)
 ---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
 92         wrapper._original_function = func
 93         return wrapper

 /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in 
 fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, 
 validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, 
 use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
 1413             use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
 1414             shuffle=shuffle,
 -> 1415             initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
 1416 
 1417     @interfaces.legacy_generator_methods_support

 /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py 
 in fit_generator(model, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, 
 callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, 
 workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
136                                      '`(val_x, val_y, 
val_sample_weight)` '
137                                      'or `(val_x, val_y)`. Found: ' +
--> 138                                      str(validation_data))
139                 val_x, val_y, val_sample_weights = 
model._standardize_user_data(
140                     val_x, val_y, val_sample_weight)

ValueError: `validation_data` should be a tuple `(val_x, val_y, 
val_sample_weight)` or `(val_x, val_y)`. Found: <__main__.generator object 
at 0x7f378513bac8>
```

Comment: What's your validation data?

Comment: @Milo Lu, I am not sure what exactly your asking.

Comment: @Milo Lu   train_gen = generator(folder, train_filenames, pneumonia_locations, batch_size=32, image_size=256, shuffle=True, augment=True, predict=False)
valid_gen = generator(folder, valid_filenames, pneumonia_locations, batch_size=32, image_size=256, shuffle=False, predict=False)

Comment: I mean the data you use for validation. You use unet, so I assume you dealing with images. How you deal with those images before you present them as input data to your neural network?

Comment: @ Milo Lu  there is a data generator class in the begining of the pipeline  https://www.kaggle.com/uds5501/cnn-segmentation-resnet-depth-5. Basically, I am trying to edit this code and change the model to Resnet50_Unet and other similar models.

Comment: @HelloWorld have you fixed this problem? If not, try updating your keras version. Also, try importing keras separately from tensorflow. I experienced this error when I used "from tensorflow import keras"